# Concatenation of SQL Queries

Tags: python, sql, csv, export, teradata

I am trying to download some tables into CSV files using TeradataSQL

The problem is that my administrator stops the connection after a certain time (I guess for security reasons) so when I try to export or download large tables/files the whole process terminates and I get an incomplete CSV File on my hard drive

Is there anyway to resume downloading from where it stopped? or maybe to append the remaining rows to the existing file?

I am open to any ideas using python or SQL

Comment: Instead of trying to find a way around your company's workload management policies, I would work with your DBAs.  Perhaps they can help you optimize your query, change WLM rules so your query doesn't timeout, etc.

Comment: For large result sets, consider using "FastExport" protocol. See the [FastExportTable.py](https://github.com/Teradata/python-driver/blob/master/samples/FastExportTable.py)  sample in the `teradatasql` documentation. Or consider using the command-line "TPT" (`tbuild`) utility.